# Android: Issue with JSONArray parsing

Tags: android, json

I am new to android and stuck with some problem in Json parsing.

```
JSONArray resultJsonArray = data.getJSONArray("detailsArr");
```

getJSONArray is showing in red colour it means some issue is with getJSONArray. But I am not able to resolve it.

JSON:

```
{"msg":"","status":true,"result":[{"conversation":"<p>sani<\/p>","attachmentName":"","attachmentURL":"","clientType":"student","repliedOn":"30-Sep-15 11:19AM","expertName":"shubham goyal","expertPic":""},{"conversation":"<p>rere<\/p>","attachmentName":"","attachmentURL":"","clientType":"expert","repliedOn":"1-Oct-15 5:31PM","expertName":"shubham goyal","expertPic":""},{"conversation":"<p>all vl<\/p>","attachmentName":"","attachmentURL":"","clientType":"student","repliedOn":"1-Oct-15 5:44PM","expertName":"shubham goyal","expertPic":""},{"conversation":"<p>asa kk<\/p>","attachmentName":"","attachmentURL":"","clientType":"expert","repliedOn":"1-Oct-15 5:45PM","expertName":"shubham goyal","expertPic":""}]}
```

Comment: Is data a JSONArray or Object?..

Comment: JSONArray but tried with JSONObject also.still it is not working.

Comment: post your code . i think problem here `data`

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya Last time also you helped me I think today also you can help me :)

Comment: Your JSON is an Object not an Array. Post your parsing code.

Comment: This is not so much a problem with Json Array parsing as with mastering basic Java. I suggest you work through a tutorial.

Comment: where is `detailsArr` ??

Comment: post your json here http://jsonprettyprint.com/

Comment: I tried this way also JSONObject object1 = data.getJSONObject(0);

Comment: detailsArr is result

Comment: @Shivam Did you solve this yet ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Bundle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html) doesn't have a method `getJSONArray()`

And your JSON string doesn't contain a key named `detailsArr`.

UPDATE:

I think what you want to do is this:

```
JSONArray resultJsonArray = new JSONObject(data.getString("detailsArr"))
        .getJSONArray("result");
```

Comment: Lets think result is detailsArr

Comment: how to access jsonarray from bundle

Comment: @Shivam I updated my answer. You should create a JSONObject first. From the JSON-formatted string, you can create one. Then you can call `getJSONArray()` with the key 'result'

Answer (score 1):

According to your JSON

it should be

```
 JSONArray resultJsonArray = data.getJSONArray("result");
```

Since result is the name of the array.

Answer (score 1):

I did't find `detailsArr` .

```
JSONObject reader = new JSONObject(Your_Json_Sring);

                JSONArray jsonArray = reader.getJSONArray("result");


                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++)
                {
                    JSONObject e = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                    String conversation = e.getString("conversation");
                  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following things:

1. Check imports, it should be like (if you are using other library - should be similar)

   ```
   import org.json.JSONArray;
   import org.json.JSONException;
   import org.json.JSONObject;
   ```
2. Check if you data is type of `JSONObject`.

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1:**
Using [this](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/) Link Create one Pojo for your Json String.

**Step 2:**
put following in your gradle than sync your gradle file

```
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.4'
```

**Step :3**
and at Last Use following code for deserialized Json

```
     Gson mGson = new Gson();
                    JsonReader reader = new JsonReader(new StringReader(YOUR_JSON_STRING));
                    final YOUR_POJO_CLASS_NAME mList = mGson.fromJson(reader, new TypeToken<YOUR_POJO_CLASS_NAME>() {
                    }.getType());
```

I hope your are clear with my solution.
Best of Luck